# Java Class extends Groovy Class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, soa-model

I am using a library called “SOA-Model”, by “Predic8”. Code can be found [here](http://www.membrane-soa.org/downloads/soa-model.htm).

Some code of the library has been written in Groovy, but I am using this library from a Java Application. I am trying to write a class “ExternalResolver” that extends “ResourceResolver”. It is similar to this example code found [here](https://github.com/membrane/soa-model/blob/3228d5a85d9e19ace24b798185db18e637c5a0eb/core/src/main/groovy/com/predic8/xml/util/ExternalResolver.groovy). And the source-code for ResourceResolver I believe can be found [here](https://github.com/membrane/soa-model/blob/master/core/src/main/groovy/com/predic8/xml/util/ResourceResolver.groovy).

However, I am writing this in **Java**, something like this:

```
import com.predic8.schema.Import;
import com.predic8.xml.util.ResourceResolver;

public class ExternalWSDLResolver extends ResourceResolver {

    public Object resolve(Object input, String baseDir){
        //some code here to do the customised resolving
    }
}
```

Now, the above all works fine if compiling in Eclipse.

However, when I try to compile on IntellijIDEA, it forces me to implement several more methods. Essentially methods that implement:

```
 - implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(String s, Object o)
 - implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject.getProperty(String s)
 - implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject.setProperty(String s, Object o)
 - implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject.getMetaClass()
 - implements groovy.lang.GroovyObject.setMetaClass(MetaClass metaClass)
```

For most I can simply get away with just returning “null”. However, if I do this for getMetaClass, my code won’t work, and returns an exception.

I therefore need to know:

- Is there a way I can shut-down these warning on Intellij? ... OR
- What I could put into getMetaClass to just get it to work? I.e. a kind-of default value.

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments to decompile the `ResourceResolver.class`, accordingly, here is the results for example for getMetaClass.

Also, for reference I have pasted the entire output here: http://pastie.org/7980007

```
public groovy.lang.MetaClass getMetaClass();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield    #27; //Field metaClass:Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass;
   4:   dup
   5:   ifnull  9
   8:   areturn
   9:   pop
   10:  aload_0
   11:  dup
   12:  invokevirtual   #25; //Method $getStaticMetaClass:()Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass;
   15:  putfield    #27; //Field metaClass:Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass;
   18:  aload_0
   19:  getfield    #27; //Field metaClass:Lgroovy/lang/MetaClass;
   22:  areturn
```

Comment: Which IDEA version are you using? Do you experience this issue on compilation or is it just highlighting in the editor?

Comment: I am using the latest version; and it is not just highlighting errors, it will not let me compile.

Comment: Could you please tell the precise version (Help | About)?
Do you have Settings | Compiler | Use external build on? Does changing this option help?

Comment: The exact version is 12.1.3, and I have access Preferences | Compiler | User External Build. I have tried toggling this, still same red error message and does not let me compile.

Comment: Which Groovy version are you using to compile? Are you using this SOA library as jars or you compile it as well as part of your project?

Comment: The SOA lib I’m using are a set of JARS (found here: http://www.membrane-soa.org/downloads/), so using out of the box and not compiling. I have not actually set-up any Groovy Compiler as my app is completely Java (i.e. my project itself has no groovy files, it is the lib that contains compiled groovy). Or, is there a compiler in-built in IDEA that I don’t know about? In any case, I seem to be extending in Java a class ‘ResourceResolver’ that is in fact Groovy by looking at the lib’s source-code. Note also again, this compiles and works well in Eclipse, just not IDEA for some odd reason.

Comment: Do you have Groovy plugin enabled in IDEA? Do you have soa/lib/groovy-all.1.8.6.jar in the module dependencies?

Strange, but I cannot reproduce this in IDEA 12.1.3. I get the wrong errors in editor (created http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108040 for that), but compilation works fine.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I do have the plug-in enabled, and also groovy-all.1.8.6.jar is in the dependencies. Nonetheless, it is still strange why this error message is appearing... Hope I can find a solution soon! ... On another note: Do you think there is anything I could write in the “`getMetaClass()`” function that could suffice to pretend that these methods has been implemented? For all of the 4 methods, simply returning null does the trick, but not for this method. I know this is a work-around solution, but at least could work for now.

Comment: Which version of the SOA library do you use BTW? Could you please try disassembling ResourceResolver class (e.g. by javap) and see if it defines those methods?

Comment: I had downloaded and using version 1.2.3 (the latest stable release). I have not done a decompile before, but am looking into this now...

Comment: I have now decompiled, and added the resulting output to the question body, if this could help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30852/discussion-between-peter-gromov-and-larry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround you can try copying `GroovyObjectSupport` code in implementing these methods, for example:

```
    public MetaClass getMetaClass() {
        if (metaClass == null) {
            metaClass = InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(getClass());
        }
        return metaClass;
    }
```

and create a metaClass field in your class as well

Comment: Thanks, but in this solution I get: `The field ResourceResolver.metaClass is not visible`, any ideas please?

Comment: I meant, you should create that field in your class as well (edited the reply).

Comment: Excellent, this method works, and allows me to execute my program as desired. While I know this is a work-around solution, this solves the problem - Thanks very much! +1